# How to edit this function so that mean can be calculated with another function in R?

Tags: r, function

Suppose we have data that looks like (in matrix format):

```
    A   B   C   D       E       F       G       H  
    2   3   12  9656    7561    214     2674    1338
    2   2   3   7057    9810    9568    1762    3293    
    3   2   3   6353    8808    7684    2405    3516
```

And three functions that calculate the Euclidean distance (`euclid`), `centroid` and `k_means` algorithm:

```
euclid <- function(points1, points2) {
  distanceMatrix <- matrix(NA, nrow=dim(points1)[1], ncol=dim(points2)[1])
  for(i in 1:nrow(points2)) {
    distanceMatrix[,i] <- sqrt(rowSums(t(t(points1)-points2[i,])^2))
  }
  distanceMatrix
}

centroid <- function(data) {
  rowMeans(data)
}

    k_means = function(x, centers, distFun) {
    prevClusters = NULL
    prevCenters = NULL
      
    repeat {
      distsToCenters = distFun(x, centers)
      clusters = apply(distsToCenters, 1L, which.min)
      centers = apply(x, 2L, tapply, clusters, mean) # If I replace 'mean' here with 'centroid', error comes
      if (identical(prevClusters, clusters)) break
        
      prevClusters = clusters
      prevCenters = centers
    }
      
    list(clusters = clusters, centers = centers)
  }

data=data # Data frame
ktest=as.matrix(data) # Turn into a matrix
centers <- ktest[sample(nrow(ktest), 5),] # Sample some centers, e.g. 5
res <- k_means(ktest, centers, euclid)
```

I'm trying to replace the commented line's 'mean' with the 'centroid' function, which basically does the same thing (gets the mean across rows). However, it doesn't work, and returns the error: `Error in rowMeans(data) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions`. How can this be fixed so that the `centroid` function works within the `k_means` function?

Comment: Edited the code to show you @RonakShah

Comment: What is this line supposed to do? `apply(x, 2L, tapply, clusters, mean)`

Comment: Go through the data set (x) and find the means. You can see this if you run the centroid function on the dataset example here that it works, and it also works when `mean` is used in the `k_means` function, but it doesn't work when `mean` is replaced with `centroid`.

Comment: Is each row an observation? Is each column a feature? @HelpNeeded3

Comment: Each row is an observation and each column is a variable name @ekoam

Comment: The `apply` function passes a vector to `tapply` which splits it according to `clusters` and then those pieces (still vectors) go to `mean`. The `rowMeans` function takes a matrix, not a vector. Try `rowMeans(1:10)`.

Comment: @dcarlson thanks for the comment - where would I include `rowMeans(1:10)`? In the `centroids` of `k_means` function?

Comment: You are using `mean` within `apply` to do exactly what `rowMeans` does. Why change anything?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this

```
euclid <- function(points1, points2) {
  f <- function(x) as.list(data.frame(t(x)))
  outer(f(points1), f(points2), function(row, col) {
    mapply(function(x, y) sqrt(sum((x - y) ^ 2)), row, col)
  })
}

centroid <- colMeans # you should use colMeans, not rowMeans

k_means <- function(x, centers, distFun) {
  prevClusters = NULL
  prevCenters = NULL
  
  repeat {
    distsToCenters = distFun(x, centers)
    clusters = max.col(-distsToCenters)
    centers = t(vapply(split.data.frame(x, clusters), centroid, numeric(ncol(x))))
    if (identical(prevClusters, clusters)) break
    
    prevClusters = clusters
    prevCenters = centers
  }
  
  list(clusters = clusters, centers = centers)
}

data <- data # Data frame
ktest <- as.matrix(data) # Turn into a matrix
centers <- ktest[sample(nrow(ktest), 5),] # Sample some centers, e.g. 5
res <- k_means(ktest, centers, euclid)
```